# Disable attribute doesn't work on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I'm trying to use knockout data-binding disable attribute on this way:

```
<input data-bind="attr: { 'disabled': tender().hasEnded() }, value: rate, valueUpdate: ['afterkeydown', 'input']," />
```

Everything going great on browser, but when I'm trying to use it on mobile, the "disabled" is disappeared after one click on it.
Anybody know that issue?

Comment: Is there a specific reason to not use the `enable` binding that comes with knockout?

Comment: Same result, just tried other way...

Comment: What mobile browser(s)?

Comment: Also, have you tried using KO's "disable" binding rather than adding the "disabled" attr?

Comment: when i'm using mobile emulator, i tried them.both

Answer (score 0):

Looking at it, you are setting disabled to be if `tender().hasEnded()` which means it will execute once.  You need to pass in the observable if you want it to update when hasEnded changes.

```
<input data-bind="attr: { 'disabled': tender().hasEnded }, value: rate, valueUpdate: ['afterkeydown', 'input']," />
```

Comment: Nop, it didn't work. also its wierd, because on web it's works fine.